# How to replace semicolons only when between double quotes?

Tags: vbscript

Using VBScript I need to replace semicolons to commas in the below text line, but only in substrings that are within double quotation marks `Chr(34)`. I tried looping with `Do While` but didn't suceeded.

```
2015/003;2015-12-15;;;;EUR;;;"170946;01";"164332;04";;"23937;99";91
```

The code I tried:

```
stop_1 = InStr(1, text, Chr(34))
stop_2 = InStr(InStr(1, text, Chr(34))+1, text, Chr(34))
Do While stop_1 > 0
  text = Replace(Mid(text, stop_1+1, stop_2-stop_1), ";", ",")
  stop_1 = InStr(1, text, Chr(34))
  stop_2 = InStr(InStr(1, text, Chr(34))+1, text, Chr(34))
Loop
```

Comment: I've added my code. It generates no records.

Answer (score 2):

You can do things like that with regular expressions and a [replacement function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic4):

```
s = "2015/003;2015-12-15;;;;EUR;;;""170946;01"";""164332;04"";;""23937;99"";91"
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = """[^""]*?"""
re.Global  = True

Function ReplaceSemicolons(m, pos, src)
  ReplaceSemicolons = Replace(m, ";", ",")
End Function

WScript.Echo re.Replace(s, GetRef("ReplaceSemicolons"))
```

Comment: Thank you, Ansgar. I got "2015/003;2015-12-15;;;;EUR;;;;;;;91" insted of "2015/003;2015-12-15;;;;EUR;;;""170946,01"";""164332,04"";;""23937,99"";91". What should I change in the script?

Comment: @PrzemyslawWojda My bad. I had missed one occurrence of the function name when cleaning up the code for my answer. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the below example. This code splits string to array of substrings, that are delimited by double quotes in source string, so the first element is the text before the first double quotes, second element is the text between double quotes, and so on: odd elements correspond to the text out of double quotes, and even elements - within double quotes. Then loops starting from second element with index 1 (zero-based array) and step 2, thus processing the elements within double quotes only: replaces `;` with `,`. After that joins processed array to retrieve the string.

```
s = "2015/003;2015-12-15;;;;EUR;;;""170946;01"";""164332;04"";;""23937;99"";91"
a = Split(s, """")
For i = 1 To UBound(a) Step 2
    a(i) = Replace(a(i), ";", ",")
Next
s = Join(a, """")
```