# Handle comma in csv file: VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using following code to read csv file and finally the data is converted into array.

```
Function Sample(strPath) As String()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

    Open strPath For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    Sample = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
End Function
```

Following code convert each comma separated line into array.

```
SaleRows = Sample(filepath)
For Each SaleRow In SaleRows
    SaleRowArray = Split(SaleRow, ",")
Next SaleRow
```

Everything works fine but when a cell contains comma, my above function fails. Is there any way to handle comma in a particular cell?

**Sample csv**

[image]

Please observe comma in second row.

**When I get array from the comma record, I get below.**

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you're actually trying to do. Access has lots of ways to work with CSV files, manually parsing them and handling quotes and quote escapes (which you are not doing, which is why you get this error) seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: Also, if you want help with your error, you should tell us what the error is.

Comment: I added the screenshots for more details. Thanks for your valuable time, Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: how is your function failing? all it does is split the text file into lines. it does not split individual lines  .... what are you really asking?

Comment: Is there any way to get the first array element as Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.? right now first array element is Wal-Mart Stores and second array element is Inc because of comma

Comment: You need to show/explain how you are currently splitting the lines into the array elements.  At the moment you are only showing how you split the file into lines, and then you say "and finally the data is converted into array".

Comment: As others already said, code only returns lines, does not show splitting line into discrete data elements. If your data elements are delimited with comma, then I have to say no, code cannot differentiate between the comma that should be retained as literal text and comma indicating separator. Is `, Inc` the only case of literal comma? If so, do a search/replace. However, your example shown in spreadsheet does not show commas, how did you get it correctly into spreadsheet - manually typed?

Comment: In `csv`(_Comma-separated values_) commas are used to separate values,  not to be values. In an ideal case, you would coordinate with the file supplier a symbol for a comma in the text. Assuming cant: find some anchor in the data. In your case: value of filed #2 seems to be one of a choice ('Invoice' would be one option). If you see it isn't, you know there is an extra, or a missing comma before, and handle the error. Transferring data is tough when not coordinated...

Comment: Also, please update your question to show a sample of the actual csv file itself.  Showing what the csv file looks like when loaded into Excel is not very useful, as Excel has already modified what is in the file before you created your screen dump.

Comment: When you open your csv in notepad. your data will show look like. "Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.",invoice,.... so. just find string between comma. After that. if exist  "  then insert string between 2 " into your array

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34371119/2165759) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34476831/2165759) answers may be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that the strings in your CSV file are escaped with quote marks.  If you want to parse the CSV using your own code, then your code needs to be able to ignore commas which occur inside quotes.

A quick way to do this would be to use RegEx.  You could try the following:

```
Private Function changeDelimiter(line as String) as String

   Dim regEx As Object
   Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")
   regEx.IgnoreCase = True
   regEx.Global = True
   regex.Pattern = ",(?=([^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & "[^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & ")*(?![^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & "))"

   changeDelimiter = regex.Replace(line, "#|#")

End Function
```

Then change the Split() line in your code as follows:

```
SaleRowArray = Split(changeDelimiter(SaleRow), "#|#")
```

The function replaces all commas outside quote marks with #|# (which I assume won't ever come up in your input data).  You then split the lines into data fields on #|# instead of comma.

Comment: Brilliant. However, #|# just might end up in data, if for example I tell people testing the product that they cannot put #|# in text fields, because then they will do that for certain. So this is a "my little secret" kind of solution, which im not fond of. Of course I could replace those initially too before doing this replace. Or maybe delete them, and record their positions so I can put them back.